# Can't get sidebar to height: 100%

Tags: html, css

I have recently been learning CSS and i'm trying to understand why I can't get my sidebar to display correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/1/

In my code, I have added

```
html, body, .container, .sidebar, .content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Which makes the sidebar extend, but it carries an additional scroll.
There is a scroll when there is no reason for there to be a scroll. Also, If I add enough text to fill in the content div, I will not be able to see the data. See here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/5/

Notice how you can't scroll down to see "TEST CAN'T SEE TEXT". How is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/18/)

I replace selectors and add `min-height` to `html, body`. I also removed `overflow: hidden;` on the `.container` and add `height: 100vh;` to the `.sidebar` :

```
.container, .sidebar, .content {
  height: 100%;
}

div#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

html, body { 
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes but on the first jsfiddle, this does not work. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/8/

Comment: @RichardCole I don't see the problem. The jsfiddle that you provide as "proof of not working" is working fine to me. What's the deal with it?

Comment: This is almost solved, but still not. I just want to know why there's an additional space now at the bottom to scroll (https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/16/). Is there a way to remove this space?

Comment: You can fix this with calc() function, see this updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/18/

Comment: Wow, thanks very much. I'm confused why that's needed, is there just additional space by default?

Comment: You're welcome ! The 60px part is because of the top bar height, so the calc() function use the difference between the total of viewport height (vh) minus the top bar height ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve but if you set

```
html, body, .container, .sidebar, .content {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

all your content is visible.

https://jsfiddle.net/ab51xj8u/2/

Comment: Does not work when the content does not go low enough, example: https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/9/

Comment: Yes but when you take away all the <br>s, it doesn't extend to the bottom.

Comment: try the solution above^^i edited my answer. Is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ab51xj8u/2/ @Richard Cole

Answer (score 0):

Well, the awnser is very simple. With the following code:

```
html, body, .container, .sidebar, .content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

You are telling the `selectors` to be `100%` height. In this case `100%` is the height of the screen aka `viewport`. The extra space that gets added, is the `height` of the `header`. To fix this, tell the `selectors` to be minimal `100%` height.

**So change this:**

```
html, body, .container, .sidebar, .content {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**into:**

```
html, body, .container, .sidebar, .content {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bnu0Ljuo/14/